# Cancel Session ServiceBus consumer actvity from publisher

Tags: c#, azure-servicebus-queues

I am dispatching a message from the service bus publisher, & essentially doing a db polling for 5 seconds.

```
var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(object));
message.SessionId = sessionId;
return client.SendAsync(message);
```

On the consumer side, I am receiving the message and doing some processing which may or may not take more than 5 seconds. We can call `CompleteAsync()`, `AbadonAsync()` to close that session.

Can we cancel from the publisher client?

Essentially, I want something like such

```
queueClient.publish(message); // publish message to queue
var tokenSource - new CancellationToken();
var task = Task.Run(()=>{
    ...
}, tokenSource.Token);
if(!task.Wait(5000, tokenSource.Token))
{
  queueClient.Cancel(); // <-----Cancel/Abadon processing in service bus consumer.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try configuring the timeout for the queue client

```
MessagingFactorySettings factorySettings = new MessagingFactorySettings()
        {
            TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider("[keyName]", "[sharedAccessKey]"),
            OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        };

        MessagingFactory messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.Create(serviceBusUri, factorySettings);
        QueueClient Client = messagingFactory.CreateQueueClient("[QueueName]");
```